# Angular 2 Generate Class Name Based on ngFor Index

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm running into a problem with creating a dynamic class name based on the Angular 2 ngFor loop index. I had to use the following syntax because Angular 2 does not like ngFor and ngIf on the same element.

With this syntax, how can I create a dynamic class name with the value of index at `{{index}}`. I know this isn't proper A2 code, but I put it in my code example to show you where I would like the value to appear.

```
<div class="product-detail__variants">
    <template ngFor #variant [ngForOf]="variants" #index="index">
        <div *ngIf="currentVariant == index">
            <div class="product-detail-carousel-{{index}}">

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

The value "variants" is an empty array of a set length. "variant" thus has no value.

"currentVariant" is a number that by default equals 0.

**EDIT**: This code above is correct. I had another extraneous error that I thought was connected to this code.

Comment: have you tried with `ngClass` ? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html

Comment: My code apparently works and another extraneous error was throwing it off. This code is correct!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem ;-)

There are two ways to set classes for a specific element:

- The way you do with curly brackets:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div class="product-detail__variants">
        <template ngFor #variant [ngForOf]="variants" #index="index">
          <div *ngIf="currentVariant == index">
            <div class="product-detail-carousel-{{index}}">
              Test
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    `,
    styles: [
      '.product-detail-carousel-2 { color: red }'
    ]
  })
  ```

  `Test` is displayed only for the third element (index 2) and in red.
- As suggested by @Langley using the `ngClass` directive

  ```
  import {NgClass} from 'angular2/common';

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div class="product-detail__variants">
        <template ngFor #variant [ngForOf]="variants" #index="index">
          <div *ngIf="currentVariant == index">
            <div class="product-detail-carousel-{{index}}">
              Test
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    `,
    styles: [
      '.product-detail-carousel-2 { color: red }'
    ],
    directives: [ NgClass ]
  })
  ```

  The different is that you need to specify the NgClass directive within the `providers` attribute of your component. Again `Test` is displayed only for the third element (index 2) and in red.

Your following sentences: "The value `variants` is an empty array of a set length. `variant` thus has no value. `currentVariant` is a number that by default equals 0.". How do you expect something to be displayed if your array is empty. An `ngFor` is an iteration...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I'm not trying to display a value, I'm merely attempting to loop a set number of times based on a value "numVariants" that is translated into an array length in order for ngFor to loop (since ng-repeat no longer exists). 

Apparently I had another extraneous error that was affecting my code and my Angular 2 code was already correct. Thank you for verify it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking to add a specific class based on the index, you can do something like this. I personally prefer the syntax here too. Let's say you wanted to add `last-para` to the last paragraph from an array:

```
<p
  *ngFor="let p of paragraphs; let i = index"
  [class.last-para]="i >= paragraphs.length - 1">
  {{p}}</p>
```